# Do I track changes to my data in a data lake?

Tags: business-intelligence, scd, data-lake

Recently I'm discovering the data lake world, I'm planning on setting up a data lake with ADL. One of the things I'm not sure on is how a data lake is supposed to track changes over time/handle different version from a source.

I've come across site that claim that a data lake serves data as is, other state that data should be timestamped or the folder structure should reflect a timestamp.

Anyway, any best practices?

Cheers!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Often there are different zones in a data lake. Here is a [good explanation of common zones](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2017/12/30/zones-in-a-data-lake). In the Raw zone, data is typically unchanged from source. It might be incremental loads of what records changed since the last load, or it could be a full copy of the data source entity. That is typically where you will see timestamped folders for each entity. As an example, you might have the following folder structure.

Raw Data

```
Organizational Unit

      Subject Area

           Original Data Source

                Object

                     Date Loaded

                          File(s)
```

Users typically don't query the Raw zone. It is acting as a historical archive of the data.

Users will often query Curated zone. This zone usually contains a subset of data from Raw that has been transformed to meet user needs. Often, this contains a copy of what the entity currently looks like, omitting older versions because that is what analysts/data scientists want to see, or because that is what needs to feed into another application that sources data from the data lake. You can find a good explanation of Raw and Curated zones [here](https://www.sqlchick.com/entries/2016/7/31/data-lake-use-cases-and-planning).

So it's possible that you would have both timestamped data where you track changes as well as a current snapshot. What you have probably read is that a data lake should allow you to be able to recreate what an entity looked like at a specific time, and that can be accomplished in Raw. But other zones cater to your organization's data needs, whether that is current, all history, or snapshots as of specific dates.

Comment: Thanks! So basically a data lake doesn't keep changes like a datawarehouse (type 2 scd for instance). If I understand you correctly it either receives a full load or a delta load (some kind of CDC).

Comment: Yes, your data lake would typically receive a full or delta load from the source, and you would store that unchanged. If you want something like a type 2 SCD, you can create that and put it in the curated zone. Whether this is necessary depends on which users and applications need this and should get this from the data lake vs another location like a DW.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I needed to know!

Comment: Amendment to this: Databricks Delta Lake can track changes in the data lake. See https://databricks.com/product/delta-lake-on-databricks for more info.